# SAS - Need to make the filepath used in an INFILE statement dynamic

Tags: sas

I have a SAS procedures that runs every morning and it takes in a raw data file for the day called "Filename_20141117.txt". The last part of the file name is changing everyday to the date for that day.

I want to make the INFILE statement in my SAS script smarter so that it knows to get the current day's file. I was trying to do a date concatenation, something like this:

infile cat('G:\Finance\RawData\Filename_',year(today()),month(today()),day(today()),'.txt')

Also, is there a way to declare variables and work with them in SAS, and not have them created as a table in your output? I'm a C/C#/VB programmer learning to program in SAS.
I was thinking that i could make 3 string variables - day, month, and year.  Populate each variable with the corresponding value using the Day(), Month() and Year() function, with Today() as the date input. Then i was going to take these 3 variables and concatenate them to get my '20141118' that would be located at the end of the .txt file.

However it doesn't like me doing this.  If anyone knows how to do this that would be fantastic. I'm very new to SAS Programming and its concepts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not enough credit for good questions on this site in general, but this is good, shows you've had an attempt at something and shows some prior research before asking for help. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most basic version of your statement would be:

```
INFILE "G:\Finance\RawData\Filename_%sysfunc(today(),yymmddn8.).txt";
```

To explain fully:

- `%sysfunc` is a macro function in SAS which allows you to use data-step functions in open code, it takes one (optionally two) arguments:

  1. The first argument of `%sysfunc` is the data-step function in question, in this case we want the value of `TODAY()`, so that is used.
  2. The second argument (optional) provides the SAS format in which the result should be returned. The SAS format of choice for the date representation you need is `yymmddn8.` (literally year_year_month_month_day_day, the `n` represents 'no-separators', and 8 is the length). (e.g. 20141118)

If we were to omit the second argument, we'd get the number of days since `01JAN1960`.

If I were to run the statement today it would look like this:

```
INFILE "G:\Finance\RawData\Filename_20141118.txt";
```

Also, use of double-quotes here is required because we are using a macro function. If we used single quotes, it would look for a file with the unresolved value of the string above and would most likely fail.

To check what it would resolve to, simply add `%PUT` to the front of the line, and then just run that line in isolation. The log will show what is returned.

Comment: Ahh thanks so much for this. Would i still need to put in the bars to concatenate the values ie: INFILE "G:\Finance\RawData\Filename_"||%sysfunc(today(),yymmddn8.)||".txt";

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to, it should all resolve correctly without any need for those.

Edited the answer to show a way of checking before you run it.

Comment: Note: It should all resolve correctly provided you use double quotes as @mjsqu did rather than single quotes. Macro references do not resolve within single quotes. +1, great answer.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm going to need to find a good book/course on SAS Programming. I can see myself needing to fix things like this in the future.  Thanks again!

Comment: http://www.lexjansen.com/cgi-bin/saspapers_query.php contains links to all of the previous SUGI (SAS User Group International) meeting docs, and they're very useful.